# Simple thread crashes Android app

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I found a very peculiar issue when creating an launching a thread inside an Android app.

If I have the following class thread:

```
public class TroubleThread extends Thread{
    boolean running;

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return running;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean running) {
        this.running = running;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (isRunning()){
        }//end while
    }//end run
}
```

and add it somewhere in the Activity's onCreate(...) method like:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    TroubleThread  myThread;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //....
        myThread = new TroubleThread();
        myThread.setRunning(true);
        myThread.start();
    }
}
```

the app will crash.

But if I change the run() method to:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        while (running){ //NOTE THE USE OF DIRECT FIELD ACCESS INSTEAD OF METHOD
        }//end while
    }//end run
```

it stops from crashing.

Even if I solved my problem by using locks, notify() and wait() the question still remains:

Why when using direct access to the field the app continues to work while when using the method it crashes?

Comment: are you that you were using `boolean running;` and not `Boolean running` ? Could you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Have you tried initializing the value so that `getRunning()` surely returns something instead of a uninitialized var? Also, whats the question being asked here, you seem to have fixed your crash... ?

Comment: Which is your error?

Comment: @Shark I solved my problem in the code taking another path and not using this solution (which I would prefer). Fixing the crash by using another solution does not make this problem invalid. I would like to know why it crashed and if possible, in the future, to use it.

Comment: @Joseph82 the application simply crashes.

Comment: Without any stacktrace?

Comment: I wonder this is not the thread fault. Maybe it's your code.

Comment: @Joseph82 It simply says: "App isn't responding. Do you want to close it? Wait | OK"

Comment: @Alex did you try to make `running` `volatile`?

Comment: I think that the problem is not your TroubleThread, but the UI-thread, that probably is waiting for something that requires a lot of time. I have tested your solution with both direct access to the boolean and through get method, and it works fine. So, I think that it should depend on what you are trying to do in the UI-thread. However, probabily you simply need to synchronize you access to the shared variable.

Comment: @Alex "isn't responding" does not mean "crashes". Looks like it get into infinite loop. Try to declare "boolean running" as volatile.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since you did not provide a MCVE, other people cannot reproduce your problem.  That is unfortunate because it means we cannot be sure what the real cause of the problem is.  We can **only** propose hypotheses.

Some people have hypothesized that your problem is due to something else; e.g. an infinite loop on the GUI thread.  That is plausible, but there is no clear evidence for this.  (And we can't see the code ....)

My hypothesis is that this is a "memory visibility" issue.  The Java Language Specification has a chapter that defines the circumstances under which one thread is *guaranteed* to see a value written to memory by another thread.  The rules are rather complicated and technical, but the essence is that you need to analyzing whether there is a *happens before* relationship between a memory write by one thread and a subsequent memory read by another thread.  A number of things will give you that relationship:

- the threads write / reading a shared volatile variable
- the threads synchronizing using the same lock
- a thread start
- a thread join
- completion of a constructor (for `final` variables)

However, none of these things exist in your program with respect to the `running` variable.  This means that there is **no guarantee** that the thread that is looping on the `running` variable will see the results of the `setRunning` call made by the other thread:

- It might see the changes immediately
- It might see the changes later
- It might *never* see them

All three behaviors are possible .... in the absence of a *happens before* relationship.

So why does one version of the code behave differently to the other?

We can't be sure.   To actually be sure, someone would need to do a deep analysis of the native (machine) code for your example.  It could be something to do with (legal) reordering that the optimizer has done in one case and not the other.  It could be a subtle timing effect.

But either way, the JLS says the the compiler is *not obliged* to make sure that the write is visible.  Why?  Because this code *breaks the rules* of the memory model.

Solutions:

In this case, the simplest solution is to declare `running` as `volatile`.

Another solution is to declare `isRunning()` and `setRunning` as `synchronized` methods.

Either of these are sufficient to provide the *happens before* relationship ... and guarantee that `isRunning()` sees the update made by `setRunning()`.